# peoplepicker AddUserKeys using user id

Tags: office-365, 2016, people-picker

I am trying to add user keys based on the ID of the people

```
var actionowner = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.owner_TopSpan;
actionowner.AddUserKeys('909');
```

This works when I just pass the Title of People and groups, but I want to pass their ID as there are multiple matches when I pass the Title

For Example, the below code works, but in some cases like having two groups `all users` & `all` it will throw an error saying that there are more than one match

```
var actionowner = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.owner_TopSpan;
    actionowner.AddUserKeys('Vignesh S');
```

Answer (score 1):

unfortunatelly you can't load a people picker by using the id of the user using the AddUserKeys method.

One suggestion: get the user name/title/display name by using the rest call /_api/web/siteusers/getById("id") or EnsureUser and then after retrieving the username you can set it to the people picker field.